# Add column from different table to SQL query (if it finds the id in a list)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am trying to build a tricky SQL statement and I need some advice.

I have these 2 tables:

```
         subscribers
| id | name    | email              |
| 1  | John Doe| john.doe@domain.com|
| 2  | Jane Doe| jane.doe@domain.com|
| 3  | Mr Jones| mr.jones@domain.com|
```

and

```
         links
| id | campaign_id    | link                                  | id_of_user_that_clicked |
| 1  | 8              | http://somesite.com/?utm_source=news1 | 1,2,3                   |
| 2  | 8              | http://somesite.com/?utm_source=news2 | 1,2                     |
| 3  | 5              | http://somesite.com/?utm_source=news3 | 2                       |
```

To pull the name and email of Mr. Jones is fast. I run:

```
SELECT name, email FROM subscribers WHERE id IN ('3')
```

But I want to add to the result the URL that he clicked stored in the link column of the second table.

I tried to do something similar to:

```
SELECT name, email FROM subscribers WHERE id IN ('3') LEFT JOIN SELECT link FROM links WHERE (id_of_user_that_clicked LIKE '3')
```

to no avail

Notice that in the second table, I have the id stored with other id's as well. How can I match **subscribers.id** with corresponding number in **links.id_of_user_that_clicked** and have the query display the link next to the name and email.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im guessing you need to use some form of `Pivot`, and look at the userID's as separate rows for every link.  That is assuming that normalizing your data is not an option, you could have a links table and a UserID-LinkID table between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for the help. I managed to build a query to serve my purposes like this. I am pasting the code used:

```
SELECT s.name, s.email, l.link FROM subscribers s, links l WHERE s.id IN ('.$subscribers.') AND FIND_IN_SET(s.id, l.id_of_user_that_clicked)
```

`$subscribers` is a comma separated array (3456, 7865, 267, etc)

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the string to contain 3, not be like 3. Try this:

```
SELECT name, email, link FROM subscribers LEFT JOIN link on id_of_user_that_clicked LIKE '%3%' WHERE subscribers.id = '3'
```

Comment: agree, but there were only sigle digits in his example :)

Answer (score 0):

Joins are recommended in MySQL as mysql-joins are faster than subqueries, [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query) 
 your sql would be something like (assuming you want to hard-code the name)

```
 select s.name,s.email, l.campaign_id,l.link from subscribers s left outer join links l on s.id= l.id wher s.name = "Mr Jones" <br>
```

let me know if it helps!!!